# How to fetch LIST of Number from DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDBMapper class to do DB operations.
Below is the Model Class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName =  "t_asgnd_user_divisions")
public class AssignedUserDivision {

public String assignedDivId;    
public List<Integer> assignedDivName;

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "users_user_pin")
public String getId() {
    return assignedDivId;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.assignedDivId = id;
}



@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "asgnd_divs_focus_div_id") 
public void setListTitles(List<Integer> name) {
    this.assignedDivName = name;
}
 
public List<Integer> getListTitles() {
    return this.assignedDivName;
}
}
```

Userpin is primary key here, so i am calling Load function of DynamoDBMapper class like this.

```
AssignedUserDivision a =dynamoDBMapper.load(AssignedUserDivision.class, accId.toLowerCase());
```

Userpin is being retrieved from DB but in other field, its null.
I tried Using below code in Setter functions as well as i tried with List of object , List of long. All of them didn't worked

> List temp = new ArrayList<>();
> this.assignedDivName = temp;

Comment: The examples in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html) all add the `@DynamoDBAttribute` on the getter and not the setter. Perhaps that makes a difference

Comment: That was silly mistake. Thanks for looking into it.